# Google Chrome is hidden. Available on %1(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING

Tags: kde, chrome, kubuntu

I have Google Chrome, and it doesn't appear when launched. I can see it in the bottom panel, but it isn't anywhere on screen. My thought is that it was apart of an activity that got deleted, and KDE still thinks it is there.

If you hover over the icon in the panel ,you see the screenshot and get message  *Available on %1(I18N_ARGUMENT_MISSING*.

Comment: I've also uninstalled and reinstalled, and killed plasma several times.

Comment: You might try `wmctrl` to list the windows and with `-e` move them. You might try removing directory `~/.config/google-chrome/` if you are willing to lose all your chrome settings.